# Правильно ли так проверять точность работы модели?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, классификация, pytorch

Есть модель для распознования мнист цифр:

```
%%time
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(784, 392),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(392, 196),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(196, 98),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(98, 10),
    nn.LogSoftmax(),
)
loss_func = nn.NLLLoss()

learning_rate = 1e-3
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
train_log = []
for i in range(200):
    pred = model(X_train)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = loss_func(pred, y_train)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    # check accuracy
    predTest = model(X_test)
    train_log.append(torch.mean((torch.argmax(predTest, dim=1) == y_test).float())*100)

    if i % 10 == 0:
        display.clear_output(wait=True)
        plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))     
        plt.title("Accuracy on test data")
        plt.xlabel("iteration")
        plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
        plt.plot(train_log, 'r')
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()
        print(f"iter = {i+10}/{1000} loss = {loss.item()}")
        print(f"accuracy = {train_log[-1]}")
```

Правильно ли так проверять точность модели во время тренировки?
Вот если что полученный график:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Точность работы модели следует оценивать по двум параметрам:
1)Дисперсия
2)Смещение
    •   Смещение — это ошибка, возникающая в результате ошибочного предположения в алгоритме обучения. В результате большого смещения алгоритм может пропустить связь между признаками и выводом (недообучение).
    •   Дисперсия — это ошибка чувствительности к малым отклонениям в тренировочном наборе. При высокой дисперсии алгоритм может как-то трактовать случайный шум[en] в тренировочном наборе, а не желаемый результат (переобучение).

Если ваша модель показывает хорошую точность на тренировочных данных, то прогоните её через новые, с которыми она еще не знакома.
У вас в алгоритме видно хорошую точность натренировочном наборе, теперь проверяйте наличие переобучения (дисперсию) на новых данных.

Так же можно оценивать модель по разным параметрам (accuracy, loss или кастомные варианты), но loss является самым универсальным.

Comment: У меня же провеяется точность на тестовых данных, а тренируется на train данных. Разве так нельзя?

Comment: @annaFerdsf да, в целом это правильно, если требуется дальнейшее увеличение точности, лучше выводить рядом 2 графика с ошибкой на тренировочном сете и на отладочном сете (для оценки смещения/дисперсии)

Comment: @annaFerdsf если ошибка на тренировочных данных 1 в 1 совпадает с ошибкой на тестовых, то дисперсия в порядке, если на тестовых она больше, попробуйте дропаут или увеличить датасет

Comment: Спасибо, как раз пробую дропаут